# Disable ⌘+p and ⌘+s in Terminal.app

Tags: terminal, keyboard

I continually hit <kbd>⌘-P</kbd> and <kbd>⌘-S</kbd> while Terminal is in focus, due to alt-tabbing between my text editor and other programs.

Does anyone know how to disable these keys in Terminal.app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try out [Keymando](http://keymando.com/) which will let you set specific shortcuts for programs. In this case, you would set those commands to do nothing.

Another solution would be to use [iTerm 2](http://www.iterm2.com/), which allows you to specify shortcuts for keys (or to ignore).

Comment: Definitely recommend iTerm 2. Great app, and constantly has updates too!

Comment: For iTerm2 to "disable" Print: Prefs > Profiles > Default > Keys > Add shortcut key ⌘-P > Ignore.

Comment: on iterm2 if i ignore CMD+P it will allow me to map CMD+P on vim?

Comment: @ArnoldRoa was hoping for the same, no luck here though. You?

Answer (score 5):

## Removing a Default Keyboard Shortcut in OS X

### TL;DR Version

Run the following two commands in Terminal, then restart it.

```
defaults write com.apple.terminal NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Export Text As..." nil
defaults write com.apple.terminal NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Print..." nil
```

## Full Explanation

You can use the [defaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html) command to disable a built-in keyboard shortcut for an app (for a custom shortcut, just remove it from Keyboard Preferences).

To disable it, you need to know the *exact* name of the menu item the shortcut is associated with and the bundle identifier of the app.

To get an app's bundle identifier, run `osascript -e 'id of app "AppName"'` in Terminal, replacing `AppName` as appropriate.

Once you have that information, the proper command is:

```
defaults write BUNDLE_ID NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "MENU_ITEM" nil
```

Followed by a restart of the app.

## Restoring the Shortcuts

If you want to undo this, you can either remove the entries in Keyboard Preferences if they appear there (they don't always), or rewrite the `NSUserKeyEquivalents` dictionary.

First, check if you have any other shortcuts set, by running `defaults read BUNDLE_ID NSUserKeyEquivalents`.

If you only see the entries you created, then you can just run `defaults delete BUNDLE_ID NSUserKeyEquivalents` and restart the app.

If there are other entries (most likely custom shortcuts you set in Keyboard Preferences), then you need to modify the entry, read below.

### Selectively Restoring Default Shortcuts

Run `defaults read BUNDLE_ID NSUserKeyEquivalents`. You'll get some output like this:

```
{
    "Other Shortcut" = "@\\U2190";
    "Export Text As..." = nil;
    "Print..." = nil;
}
```

Remove the lines you want to reset (`Export` and `Print`), then copy the remaining output as-is; make sure to include the curly brackets. Then type (but don't yet run) `defaults write BUNDLE_ID NSUserKeyEquivalents '`. Paste your modified text after that (be sure you included the single quote before pasting), then close the single quote (`'`) and run the command. Once you restart the app, the default shortcuts should be restored, while keeping any existing ones.

Comment: Or just change it in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts.

Comment: Warning: using the `defaults write com.apple.terminal NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Print..." nil` recipe didn't work, and in fact set this to the `N` key (so typing N would trigger print dialog. Using System Preferences, Keyboard, Shortcuts as recommended by @benwiggy worked well though.

Comment: Tip: using System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts, you can hold down 4 modifier keys (shift, ctrl, alt and cmd) plus a letter to set a shortcut that you won't hit by accident.